# TinyMCE Image Upload with Laravel, without File Manager

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE as rich-text editor and when I click on image/video buttons, I want to upload it on server, which is Laravel. All the guides online shows using a file manager, however I don't want to use a File Manager in between. I want user to directly upload the image (using ajax?) and so that the image gets imported in the editor without page refresh.

I got confused where to start. Is there a way to directly uploading the image so that the user can instantly use the image/video in the editor? If so, what is the way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout justboilme on justboil.me, that's the best I know for including images in tinymce

Comment: Can you please expand your answer on how I can use it with Laravel and ajax?

Comment: Download just boil me and follow the installation instructions, i.e you copy the justboilme folder to js/tinymce/plugins.
So your justboilme folder will be jbimages, the in your plugin array in the initialization of your tinymce plugin, add jbimages and also add it to the toolbar, then you need to edit the config.php in your jbimages folder to change the folder where it uploads images to.
To submit with ajax, don't bother yourself about the submission of the image, jbimages does that, what you need to do is submit the content of the tinymce thru ajax

Answer (score 1):

use this code for your front end

```
<script>tinymce.init({

        selector:'textarea' ,
        height: 400,
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | fontsizeselect link image | media",
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '/AdminPanel/UploadNewsPhoto');
            var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var json;
                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }
                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }
                success(json.location);
            };
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            xhr.send(formData);
        },
        directionality: 'rtl',

        plugins: 'image code , media',

        /* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
        image_title: true,
        /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
        automatic_uploads: true,
        /*
          URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
          images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
          here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
        */
        file_picker_types: 'image',
        /* and here's our custom image picker*/
        file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

            /*
              Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without
              even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
              or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
              just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
              once you do not need it anymore.
            */

            input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    /*
                      Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
                      registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
                      necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
                    */
                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                    /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };

            input.click();
        }

});</script>
```

then implement your upload with laravel

```
 public function UploadNewsPhoto(Request $request)
{

    $fileFormat = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $PhotoValidFormat = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'bmp');


    if (in_array(strtolower($fileFormat), $PhotoValidFormat) && $_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $PhotoName = uniqid() . '.' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $fileSize = number_format($_FILES['file']['size'] / 1048576, 2);//to mb


        if ($fileSize <= 50) {


            if ($request->file('file')->move(base_path() . env('Photo_News_UPLOAD_PATH'), $PhotoName)) {

               return json_encode(array(

                   'location'=>'/posts/images/'.$PhotoName

               ));


            } else
                $res = -1;

        } //bad format or size not allowed for php.ini
        else {
            if (isset($_FILES['file']['error']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 1)
                $res = -1;
            else
                $res = 0;
        }

        echo json_encode(array('res' => $res));

    }


}
```

you must return 
    'location'=>'/posts/images/'.$PhotoName

Comment: Great answer. But you might as well use "images_upload_url" and not handle it by yourself (on the front-end).

Answer (score 0):

use
`tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent();`
to get the content of the tinymce plugin
So your script could be something like this
Where editor1 is the id of your textarea where you initialized tinymce on

```
<script>
    var tinymce_content = tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent()
    $.post('your_post_url',
    {
        content: tinymce_content
    },
    function(data)
    {
        //what to do when request is complete
    })
</script>
```